# Excel Advanced Filter string equal to AND string Not equal to

Tags: excel-2010

A column contains strings "abcdef" and "cdef".
A row contains either abcdef or cdef but not both.
What would the Advance filter criteria be for filtering out rows with "cdef" but not "abcdef"

Answer (score 0):

Filter drop menu on cell-> Text filter -> equals "cdef"